# Loop through data object and ouput the object filename and message for each object

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, loops

How do i loop through my ajax request for each data object and pull out the filename, message for each file? Can anyone help?

Server side controller which is parsing back a List to the client side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<FileUpload> uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{       
    WebUserSession session = (WebUserSession) req.getSession().getAttribute("webUserSession");
    String windowsUsername = session.getUsername();


    List<FileUpload> fileList = itsmService.uploadFile(files, windowsUsername, number);
    int countTrue = 0;
    int countFalse = 0;

    for (FileUpload loopFile : fileList) 
    {
        if (loopFile.getSuccess())
        {
            countTrue++;
        }
        else
        {
            countFalse++;
        }

    }



    return fileList;
}
}
```

part of ajax request Client side data object:

```
success : function(data) {
            FileUploadVisible(true);
            console.log(data);
```

}

Comment: What is displaying console.log(data) ?

Comment: The array index in the form of an object and the file name, message and success

Comment: E.gObject 0: file name = a.txt, success = true, message = "file uploaded successfully"

Comment: So, in the success function you have an array in data with all of the information you need? Why don't you do a simple for loop and like, get your data.

Comment: How do I do the for loop using data? Yes I have the array stored in data with all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but if your server returns data like:

```
[{"name":"toto.txt", "message":"bla", "success":true},{"name":"titi.txt", "message":"blabla", "success":true}]
```

You can do:

```
success:function(fileList) {
 fileList.forEach(function(file){
   console.log("File name:" + file.name + ", msg:" + file.message + ", success: " + file.success);
 })
}
```

or if you just want to display the files successfully uploaded:

```
success:function(fileList) {
   var uploadedFiles = []
   fileList.forEach(function(file){
       if (file.success) uploadedFiles.push(file.name)
     })
   }
   alert("Files uploaded: " + uploadedFiles.join(", ");
```

Comment: Can I use data ? Instead of my array fileList ?? As data has all the information I need. I'm trying to output the file names uploaded successfully and not uploaded so the user knows exactly which ones have and haven't been uploaded.

Comment: data or fileList, this is just the name of the parameter, you can use whatewer you want!

Comment: Ok and instead of adding to console log I can add an alert of all filenames uploaded ?